# How to pass Reference of a resource to a python dictionary in CFN template?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, boto3, aws-secrets-manager

I have a CFN template for "Secret automatic rotation mechanism" where i am trying to pass the "username" from a parameter file and "masterarn" using hardcoded arn.

```
      GenerateSecretString:
        SecretStringTemplate: |
          #!PyPlate
          import ast,json
          creds_dict = {}
          creds_dict["username"] = ast.literal_eval(params['pDbUserName'])[%d-1]['pUsername']
          creds_dict["masterarn"] = '<arn>'
          output = json.dumps(creds_dict)
        GenerateStringKey: "password"
```

In this code i want to pass reference of a resource being already created in the template for "masterarn". So that the code should look like:-

```
      GenerateSecretString:
        SecretStringTemplate: |
          #!PyPlate
          import ast,json
          creds_dict = {}
          creds_dict["username"] = ast.literal_eval(params['pDbUserName'])[%d-1]['pUsername']
          creds_dict["masterarn"] = !Ref mastersecret
          output = json.dumps(creds_dict)
        GenerateStringKey: "password"
```

But as this !Ref is specific to AWS cloudformation, how can push this into the python dictionary code?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: looking at the Pyplate macro itself it doesn't even use cfn-pyplates package so its functionality can't be used. However it iterates basically over all objects in your template recursively and executes 'basic' python

This means you can try to split your logic using a Fn::Join:

```
           SecretStringTemplate: !Join 
               - ""
               - 
                    - '{"username": "'
                    - | 
                      pyplate code here to generate username
                    - !Sub '", "masterarn": ${masterARN}"}
```

Does this help you any further? It's some fiddling around with single and double quotes probably but I think this should work conceptually.

<strike>What I understand from the [docs](https://cfn-pyplates.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyplates.html)  Try simply using `ref('resourceLogicalIdhere')` instead of !ref in your python code.</strike>

Comment: i tried that already but it says that "ref" no such module found.

Comment: hey thanks man, this really helped me figure out to do next thing, which worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @LRutten, i was able to figure out on how i could take it on!

The below code worked for me:-

```
      GenerateSecretString:
        SecretStringTemplate: !Join 
            - ""
            - 
              - '{"username": "'
              - |
                #!PyPlate
                import ast
                output = {}
                output['Fn::Sub'] = f"{ast.literal_eval(params['pDbUserName'])[%d-1]['pUsername']}"
              - '","masterarn": "'
              - !Ref rRDSInstanceRotationSecretSu
              - '"}'
        GenerateStringKey: "password"
```